# I have got Socket Timeout Exception but My data submitted on server too

Tags: android, json, sockets, rest, http

I have got an prob with http post request i have set time out and on socket time out exception my data submitted on server successfully how i can restrict data to submitted on server my code is following

```
try{HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
                    AppSettings.SERVICE_URL.POST_NEW_REGISTRATION);
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(
                    httpClient.getParams(), 5000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), 5000);
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("agent_id", SharedPrefrence.getUserID());
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString(),
                    "UTF-8"));
            // Set up the header types needed to properly transfer JSON
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
            // Execute POST
            //int getConnectionTimeout (HttpParams params);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            if (responseEntity != null) {
                response = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
            } else {
                response = "{'success':'FALSE'}";
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            response = "{'success':'FALSE'}";
            progressDialog.cancel();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response = "{'success':'FALSE','message':'Connection Time Out'}";
            Log.d("Ex", e.toString());
            Log.e("Ex", e.toString());
            progressDialog.cancel();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            response = "{'success':'FALSE','message':'JSON Parse Error'}";
            progressDialog.cancel();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            response = "{'success':'FALSE'}";
            progressDialog.cancel();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Plese give a short reason for down vote

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that you are getting a socket timeout exception even though the data is successfully received by the server?

If so, I think you may want to look at the value you are setting for the socket timeout - this appears to be 500ms in your code, which is quite short. It is quite possible that everything on the server side is working fine, but that the response is simply not getting to the client within 500ms.

A typical default is in the 6-10 seconds range, but it is really solution dependent so you may want to experiment. This blog post suggests some defaults for different scenarios and may be a useful reference:

- http://dev.bizo.com/2013/04/sensible-defaults-for-apache-httpclient.html

Comment: i have set time out too low so that i got time out excetion every time and yes i got exception and my data submitted on server too ... i dont want to submit data on server when i an getting socket time out exception thanks for quick response

Answer (score 0):

probably your API call takes more than 500 ms, increase it and try again.

Comment: i have set time out too low so that i got time out excetion every time and yes i got exception and my data submitted on server too ... i dont want to submit data on server when i an getting socket time out exception thanks for response